# Replacing $ifNull with $cond in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I am thinking of migrating my app from MongoDB 3.6 to AWS DocumentDB. I am checking to see if everything is supported and I found `$ifNull` (aggregation) in the code. DocumentDB does not support `$ifNull`.

For a sample set of documents:

```
[
  { "hostname": "foo", "name": "a", "is_valid": true },
  { "hostname": "foo", "name": "b", "is_valid": false },
  { "hostname": "foo", "name": "c" }
]
```

I want to group document by the hostname field and if the is_valid field does not exist, make it true. This is the current aggregation query:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$hostname",
    boxes: {
      $push: {
        name: "$name",
        is_valid: { $ifNull: ["$is_valid", true]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns:

```
{
  "_id": "foo",
  "boxes": [
    { "name": "a", "is_valid": true },
    { "name": "b", "is_valid": false },
    { "name": "c", "is_valid": true }
  ]
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$hostname",
    boxes: {
      $push: {
        name: "$name",
        is_valid: { $cond: [{$ne: ["$is_valid", null]}, "$is_valid", true]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that returns:

```
{
  "_id": "foo",
  "boxes": [
    { "name": "a", "is_valid": true },
    { "name": "b", "is_valid": false },
    { "name": "c" }
  ]
}
```

How can I translate `$ifNull` into an equivalent `$cond`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for $ifNull was added to Amazon DocumentDB in January 2021.

Comment: Confirmed in the release notes https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/release-notes.html#release-notes.01-15-2021 and the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html

Answer (score 0):

Changing `$ne` to `$gt` works.

```
{ 
  $group: {
    _id: "$hostname",
    boxes: {
      $push: {
        name: "$name",
        is_valid: { $cond: [{$gt: ["$is_valid", null]}, "$is_valid", true]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If someone knows why this works, I would feel better understanding it more.